# Train model to predict simple linear function

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, keras

I'm trying to use logistic regression using keras, it's one of my very first experiments in ML. Let's say I want to predict values for some very simple continuous function with only 1 argument, like `y = x*10`

I tried to train model like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# fix random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(7)

# function
curve = np.vectorize(lambda x: x*10)

# data
Xideal = np.arange(1, 15.5, 0.005)
Yideal = curve(Xideal)
X = Xideal[1::5]
Y = curve(X)

# Model 
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit

model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=1000, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

# Evaluate

# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(Xideal, Yideal)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[0], scores[0]*100))
```

Gives me result of 

`2624/2900 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s
acc: 2.38%
loss: 44.35%`

Not sure why it's just 2.38% accuracy. I was experimenting with different models with different activation functions, batch sizes and epochs but got just at maximum 10% accuracy. I think I miss here something basic

Comment: 1) Logistic regression actually is a classifier, not a regressor. But you seem to want regression for your task. 2) You should really preprocess your data (standardization/normalization; one of the more important rules with NNs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this linear data, a single Dense layer will be enough.
Instead of rmsprop I would just use gradient descent.

I've created an ipython notebook for you: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/lhk/6650e4fb85f625199ee5be6d52cbbd0d

Please note: In the plot I had to move the two lines manually apart from each other. That's why there's the -2.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why did you choose batch size of 10?

Comment: The gradient in the loss will be calculated for the entire batch, the update of the weights in the network will be an average of the derivatives wrt individual samples in the batch. This means: Huge batch -> strong smoothing effect of the gradients. For some problems it can help to have huge batches in order to make training more stable. A small batch has the advantage that there are more batches in each epoch: there will be more update steps per epoch. For this problem, there is a global optimum. The solution should be well conditioned. So I decreased the batch size for faster updates.